# Short science fiction story about a dead scientist who invented a telescope without a lens

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I've read this story years ago and haven't been able to find it since. I hope I remember it right and don't mix it up with other stories:

Three scientists go through the things of their old friend who just died. They talk and drink and, if I remember it right, they find a little device/object which they can't identify. One of the scientists remembers that their dead friend talked about an invention he made, an oculum (or something like that.)

I think the next day he realises that the invention is not an oculum, but ANocculum (without lens). He puts the little device up to his eye and it is a telescope that works without a lens.

I hope someone knows this story and I can finally read it again.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When approximately was "years ago?"  Can you recall where you might have read it?  An anthology, a magazine, online...

Comment: I think it was an anthology, but not a newly published one. Maybe from the 70ies or 80ies??

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is quite possibly *[Anniversary](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62728)*, a short story by Isaac Asimov that was a sequel to one of his first short stories, *Marooned off Vesta*.

From the [wikipedia summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anniversary_(short_story)):

> Warren Moore and Mark Brandon are two of the three survivors of the
> wreck of the Silver Queen in the asteroid belt [told in "Marooned off
> Vesta"]. Every year, they meet on the anniversary of the disaster to
> celebrate their survival. On the 20th anniversary, Brandon has a
> surprise: he appears at Moore's house with Michael Shea, the third
> survivor...
>
> When Shea mentions that Trans-space Insurance is still searching for
> wreckage from the ship, 20 years later, it occurs to Brandon that
> there must have been something extremely valuable on board, and that
> Trans-space still hasn't found it. The three men learn via Moore's
> Multivac terminal that Quentin had a prototype of a revolutionary new
> invention with him on the ship, and that it is still missing. The only
> clue is the description of the device as "**an opticon**", an apparent
> reference to a light-manipulating device...
>
> Moore realizes that he has had the device all along, having idly
> picked it up as a souvenir during his spacewalk, and that its actual
> name is "**anopticon**", meaning a device without lenses. An
> apparently useless tube a few inches long, it seems to employ
> force-fields instead of conventional optics and can be used as a
> powerful microscope or telescope.

If the OP read it in an anthology in the 70s or 80s, it was probably in *[Asimov's Mysteries](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?27280)*.

Comment: I thought so many years about this story and now you gave me an answer in only 10 minutes! Thank you so much, you can't imagine how happy i am right now! :D

Comment: @Annika Don't forget to mark the answer as correct by clicking the little checkmark on the left, below the voting buttons :-)

Comment: It's also included frequently included in Asimov anthologies sold by the Science Fiction Book Club from the 1980's through the 2000's, ex: Isaac Asimov: The Complete Stories.  That's where I first read it and recognized the story immediately from the question.  The number of times I check these questions and have no idea and finally run into one I've read 50 times.  Well, I just ... excellent answer.  :-)

Comment: Didn't recall the title but I knew the story just from the preview.